# What is the glory of hymn of shiva in spiritual life?

Tags: shiva, shiva-lingam

What is the glory of hymn of Shiva in spiritual life ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mahimna Strotra

> दीक्षा दानं तपस्तीर्थं योगयागादिकाः क्रियाः।
> महिम्नः स्तव पाठस्य कलां नार्हन्ति षोडशीम्॥३५॥
>
> Initiation into spiritual life, charities, austerities, pilgrimages, practice of
> yoga, performance of sacrificial rites - none of these give even a sixteenth
> part of the merit that one gets by reciting the hymn on the greatness of
> Shiva. (36)

Just one hymn of shiva and all others even sacrificial acts are not in comparision to even sixteenth part of it.